# Node XPath- Select Node ignoring only one particular child Node

Tags: xml, xpath, local-name

```
<a> 
 <b>
     <c>A2</c>
 </b>
</a>
```

Here I want an xpath to pick node only if the node value is c,d,e ...(or it can be any other value) and ignore only if the node is 'z' (in place of c)

I tried following expression but it is not working

```
xPath: //*[local-name() = 'a']//*[local-name() = 'b']/*[not(local-name() = 'z')]
xPath: //*[local-name() = 'a']//*[local-name() = 'b']/*[not(starts-with(local-name(),'z'))]
```

Comment: Works for me. Can you be more specific about what "is not working" means for you? Are you looking specifically for just children of `b` that are children of `a` and not anywhere else in the doc?

Comment: Have you tried using `/` instead of `//` everywhere? I'm assuming your actual input is more complicated than your example and using `//` might be selecting elements at levels you're not intending.